# How to install eigen3 using pip on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, eigen

I want to install a package using pip install command, the package has eigen3 as a dependency, how do I install eigen3 with pip?

I downloaded eigen3 zip and extracted it, I don't know what else to do, how do I make pip install eigen3 or know where it is, I don't know how to use --global-option if it solves the issue.

Comment: what windows are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: What is the software and how does it declare eigen3 as a dependency? eigen3 is C++ package; you need one of its Python wrappers.

Comment: "graphkernels" package